# How to check if string contains valid characters in C?

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, error-handling, character

So we have code for a tokenizer which is admittedly kind of broken.

Now it is a given that we cannot modify this function.

It gives the correct output for the majority of cases though. Except in some cases it adds random extra junk to the end.

Now the program reads in a string and converts it into a tree for execution. At the bottommost nodes contain simple commands.

These simple commands have to be parsed for execution.

Now during parsing it turns out that the extra junk at the end hinders the execvp() call.

I wanted to ask for suggestions regarding how to eliminate the junk at the end.

I thought of using a regex to check if the string contains valid characters, and was curious if there were any standard library functions to help in this regard?

If it makes any difference - the junk character is like a box with

```
00
19
```

as its contents. It displays in gedit but not here. The origin of the junk print is the first parse, and it is not feasible to change it.

Here is a sample run of the program.

```
sgml@SGML3:~/smelly-fish$ ./timetrash exectest
 Word is: expr 3 + 8 + 9 + 8  (Junk - this character won't display)
 Temp is: expr 3 + 8 + 9 + 8  (Junk - this character won't display)
c->u.word[0] is expr
c->u.word[1] is 3
c->u.word[2] is +
c->u.word[3] is 8
c->u.word[4] is +
c->u.word[5] is 9
c->u.word[6] is +
c->u.word[7] is 8
c->u.word[8] is  (Junk - this character won't display)
c->u.word[9] is (null)
expr: syntax error
Command is: SIMPLE_COMMAND
 Word is:  expr 7 + 8 + 9 + 8  (Junk - this character won't display)
 Temp is:  expr 7 + 8 + 9 + 8 (Junk - this character won't display)
c->u.word[0] is expr
c->u.word[1] is 7
c->u.word[2] is +
c->u.word[3] is 8
c->u.word[4] is +
c->u.word[5] is 9
c->u.word[6] is +
c->u.word[7] is 8
c->u.word[8] is (Junk - this character won't display)
c->u.word[9] is (null)
expr: syntax error
Command is: SIMPLE_COMMAND
sgml@SGML3:~/smelly-fish$ ./timetrash exectest >execresults1.txt
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
sgml@SGML3:~/smelly-fish$ ./timetrash exectest
 Word is: expr 3 + 8 + 9 + 8 (Junk - this character won't display)  
 Temp is: expr 3 + 8 + 9 + 8    (Junk - this character won't display) 
c->u.word[0] is expr
c->u.word[1] is 3
c->u.word[2] is +
c->u.word[3] is 8
c->u.word[4] is +
c->u.word[5] is 9
c->u.word[6] is +
c->u.word[7] is 8
c->u.word[8] is (Junk - this character won't display)   
c->u.word[9] is (null)
expr: syntax error
Command is: SIMPLE_COMMAND
 Word is:  expr 7 + 8 + 9 + 8 
 Temp is:  expr 7 + 8 + 9 + 8 
c->u.word[0] is expr
c->u.word[1] is 7
c->u.word[2] is +
c->u.word[3] is 8
c->u.word[4] is +
c->u.word[5] is 9
c->u.word[6] is +
c->u.word[7] is 8
c->u.word[8] is 
c->u.word[9] is (null)
expr: syntax error
Command is: SIMPLE_COMMAND
sgml@SGML3:~/smelly-fish$
```

Comment: "adds random extra junk to the end" - sounds like a buffer overrun problem. You're just asking for trouble if you don't fix it.

Comment: Exactly my thought as well, the tokenizer is not appending a /0 char to the end which marks the end of the string, and instead is leaving you with the value of the token plus as many more characters until a /0 just happens to appear later in memory, which leaves you with a bunch of extra chars.  No fool-proof way to fix this other than fixing the tokenizer (or possibly fixing the size of the char array that catches the token, maybe it just doesn't have enough room in there to include the end char?)

Comment: A character consisting of a box with 4 digits (2 over 2) is a Unicode character that can't be displayed; the number (in your case `0019`) is the hex code. Yours seems to be the control character "END OF MEDIUM." Whether it's supposed to be there or is a result of overflowing, no way to tell without seeing code.

Comment: So is there a way to strip check for this particular character?

I realise it is asking for trouble - but we need a quick and dirty fix for now.

Like in this line - c->u.word[8] is (Junk - this character won't display). If I can check for this exception, I can assign correct values to the array.